# Autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation interpretation

Tags: data-visualization, autocorrelation

I am learning about ACF and PACF graphs. I am not sure I understand how to interpret the one I got for my data.

I have searched google for some ACF and PACF examples, and I found some samples of different processes, however, the one I am getting doesn't look similar to any. Does this means there is no seasonality, trend and other processes?

I have also created [graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK7vo.png) for unstandardized residuals of my model, do not understand what those means? Does it somehow relate to white noise?

[image: ACF & PACF of y and residuals]

Comment: How many observations do you have? Sixteen?

Comment: Yes. Sixteen. These are not real data, some hypotethical data for learning from some lectures.

Comment: There's little reason to believe there's any autocorrelation structure there, but with 16 observations you have little power.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither the ACF nor the PACF are giving any reason to suppose an ARMA process, trend or seasonality: none of the correlations approach significance at conventional levels.  Note that sixteen observations is very few to fit a time series model, so the only effects you might see would be very large ones.

The residuals of the process are the differences between the observations & the fitted values from your model.  If your model's good they should be white noise—uncorrelated with zero mean. You don't say what model you fit; but the residuals look a little less like white noise than your original series, so it's probably not a good one.