# Why is stl function giving significant seasonal variation with random data

Tags: time-series, seasonality, loess

I plotted with following code with stl (Seasonal Decomposition of Time Series by Loess) function:

```
plot(stl(ts(rnorm(144), frequency=12), s.window="periodic"))
```

It shows signficant seasonal variation with random data put in code above (rnorm function). Signficant variation is seen every time this is run, though the pattern is different. Two such patterns are shown below:

[image]

[image]

How can we rely on stl function on some data when it shows seasonal variation. Does this seasonal variation need to be seen in view of some other parameters? Thanks for your insight.

The code has been taken from this page: [Is this an appropriate method to test for seasonal effects in suicide count data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144745/is-this-an-appropriate-method-to-test-for-seasonal-effects-in-suicide-count-data/145788#145788)

Comment: That happens because there are "patterns" in random data, if your fitting technique has enough parameters.

Comment: The term "significant" here doesn't seem to reflect any kind of significance testing.

Comment: Stl is a nonparametric data driven method, so there is no way to quantify presence absence of seasonal  uncertainties via significance testing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Loess decomposition is intended to *smooth* the series by applying averages to the data so that it collapses into components, e.g. the trend or seasonal, that are interesting for the analysis of the data. But this methodology is not intended to do a formal *test for the presence of seasonality*.

Although in your example `stl` returns a smoothed pattern of seasonal periodicity, this pattern is not relevant to explain the dynamics of the series. In order to see that, we can compare the variance of each component with respect to the variance of the original series.

```
set.seed(123)
x <- ts(rnorm(144, sd=1), frequency=12)
a <- stl(x, s.window="periodic")
apply(a$time.series, 2, var) / var(x)
#   seasonal      trend  remainder 
# 0.07080362 0.07487838 0.81647852
```

We can see that it is the remainder what explains most of the variance in the data (as we would expect for a white noise process).

If we take a series with seasonality, the relative variance of the seasonal component is much more relevant (although we don't have a straightforward way to test it since loess is not parametric).

```
y <- diff(log(AirPassengers))
b <- stl(y, s.window="periodic")
apply(b$time.series, 2, var) / var(y)
#    seasonal       trend   remainder 
# 0.875463620 0.001959407 0.117832537
```

The relative variances indicate that seasonality is the main component explaining the dynamics of the series.

---

A careless look at the plot from `stl` can be deceptive. The nice pattern returned by `stl` may make us think that a relevant seasonal pattern can be identified in the data, but a closer look may reveal that it's not actually the case. If the purpose is to decide on the presence of seasonality, loess decomposition can be useful as a preliminary view but it should be complemented with other tools.

Comment: In your AirPassengers example, there is no trend coming in output, while there is a clear trend on plot(AirPassengers). The trend comes to 0.86 (with seasonal of only 0.1) if "diff(log(AirPassengers))" statement is removed. What should be done?

Comment: I gave an example that is numerically clear. In practice, just by comparing the variance of the smoothed components may not be enough to reach a conclusion 
about the presence of seasonality. For example, as you found in this case, if the trend is not removed by taking differences, the variance of the trend 
dominates the variance of the seasonal component. The question is: is a relative variance of 0.1 large enough to consider this component relevant? The problem is that, based on loess, there isn't a straightforward way to test whether the variance of the component is significant.

Comment: Like I said, what we should do in this and other cases is to use other methods to test for the presence of seasonality. See for example the second part of my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147087/how-to-interpret-these-acf-and-pacf-plots/147092#147092). Once we have concluded that seasonality is present in the data, we can use loess to obtain the pattern of this component.

Comment: Just for more clarification, how does relative variance show how much a part of the decomposition plays in the overall data? I.E 70% seasonal, 20% trend. etc.

Comment: @TedMosby I don't understand your question. It's a percentage, the higher the more relevant the component is.

Comment: @javlacalle sorry for the confusions. I guess my question is why does the variance of the part divided by variance of the whole = how relevant the component is? I know this is incredibly basic..

Comment: @TedMosby The variance is a measure of variability/dispersion in the data. The sum of the variances of the components (e.g., trend, seasonal) and the variance of the remainder add up to the variance of the original series. In this way, by comparing the variance of a component with the variance of the original series, we can get an idea of how much relevant the component is (i.e., how much of the variability in the data is explained by the component).

Comment: Do you have any ideas why the variances of trend, seasonality and the remainder not add up to 1 after they get standardized by the variance of the original series?

Comment: @de1pher I don't know. I thought it could be due to some observations that are missed in the lags of the filters employed by the procedure; but 
`sum(apply(a$time.series[(n+1):(144-n),], 2, var) / var(x[(n+1):(144-n)]))` 
does not add up to 1 (trying some values `n=2,7,12,...`). It seems more relevant when the data does not have a seasonal component.

Answer (score 2):

In a similar vein I have seen the utilization of Fourier Models to non-seasonal data , forcing a seasonal structure into the fit and forecast values, causing a similar (gasp !) result. Fitting a presumed model gives the user what he is imposing/presuming which is not always what good analytics would suggest/deliver.

Comment: `stl()` is not based on Fourier ideas. Although I have yet to see anyone advocating "mindless" analysis, note that any model family fitted could be regarded as imposed or presumed. The question is how far any procedure offers scope for users to realise if and how it works badly for a particular dataset.

Comment: @NickCox quite true ....